# How to send emoji with Twitter Python lib

Tags: python, twitter, emoji

I have a script done which uses the twitter lib to send a twitter DM.
I've tried a number of ways to include codes which render on iOS 8+ as emoji without luck.  Google has been unkind.

Examples:

`msg += u'\xF0\x9F\x9A\x80'` gives me no rocket.  I get a d with a line through the top.

`msg += u'U+1F684'` gives me the code not a train

As I can include emoji when I send a twitter DM to a user, the server clearly handles meta data pertaining to emoji.  As emoji is a UTF-8 character set rather than a font, I'm surprised that in the first example I'm getting representation in the font the twitter DM arrives in.

How can I send such characters from python 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [wide Unicode escape](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code):

```
msg += u'\U0001F684'
```

However, not all Python 2 builds support the wide Unicode characters (have 32-bit wide characters); usually the Windows builds can have 16-bit UCS-2 strings.

Answer (score 0):

OK got it.

`msg += u'\U0001f468'` gives me an old (white) man

`msg += u'\U0001f468\U0001f3ff'` gives me an old (afro-caribbean) man.